# What's an easy way to perform this complicated SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Given these entries in a table `table`:

```
user    entry

A       1   
A       2   
A       5
A       6
B       1   
B       2   
B       3
B       4
B       5
B       6
C       1
C       4
D       1
D       2
D       5
D       6
D       7
D       9
```

And we have a subset `entries_A` to work with, which is the array `[1,2,5,6]`.

**Problems:**

1. Find all users that have the same entries [1,2,5,6] and more, e.g. [1,2,5,6,7] or [1,2,3,5,6].
2. Find all users that have a lot of the same entries (and more), e.g. [1,2,5,9] or [2,5,6,3].

The best solution to the first problem I could come up with, is the following select query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user AS u FROM table WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE entry=1 AND user=u)
                                    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE entry=2 AND user=u)
                                    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE entry=5 AND user=u)
                                    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE entry=6 AND user=u)
```

On the other hand, I get a feeling there's some algebraic vector-problem lurking below the surface (especially for problem two) but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

All ideas welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to perform this type of query is using aggregation and `having`.  Here is an example.

To get A's that have exactly those four elements:

```
select user
from table
group by user
having sum(entry in (1,2,5,6)) > 0 and
       count(distinct entry) = 4;
```

To get A's that have those four elements and perhaps others:

```
select user
from table
group by user
having sum(entry in (1,2,5,6)) > 0 and
       count(distinct entry) >= 4;
```

To order users by the number of matches they have and the number of other matches:

```
select count(distinct case when entry in (1, 2, 5, 6) then entry end) as Matches,
       count(distinct case when entry not in (1, 2, 5, 6) then entry end) as Others,
       user
from table
group by user
order by Matches desc, Others;
```

Comment: Thanks for the last query. I didn't ask for it, but I needed something pretty much exactly like it.

Comment: Don't know where you got that from, but `having entry in (1,2,5,6)` doesn't work at all, as only aggregate functions work in the having clause.

Comment: Looks better, yes :) +1

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem:

```
SELECT user FROM (
    SELECT
    DISTINCT user
    FROM 
    table
    WHERE entry IN (1,2,5,6)
) a JOIN table b ON a.user = b.user
GROUP BY a.user
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
```

For the second problem just decrease the count in the having clause.

Comment: That looks like the simple and elegant solution I'm looking for. I'll accept it when I'm sure it's 100% right.

Comment: Note that this will only work if the combination user-entry is unique. Otherwise this query will also return users that have e.g., four entries with value 1

Comment: @hage, yes, I realized that. I assume that's why fancyPants edited his answer.

Comment: No, hage's concern is still valid.

Comment: To avoid those entries I mentioned you need to simulate the universal quantifier in SQL (there is not explicit operation for this). First link I found [see here](http://www.mattwarden.com/articles/univquantsql.shtml.old)

Comment: @fancyPants, could you explain what was wrong with your initial solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would to your first query (though I think Gordon Linoff's answer is more efficient):

```
select distinct user from so s1 
where not exists ( 
    select * from so s2 where s2.entry in (1,2,5,6) 
       and not exists ( 
          select * from so s3 where s2.entry = s3.entry and s1.user = s3.user
    )
);
```

For the second problem, you would need to specify what `a lot` should mean... three, four, ...

Comment: Nope... `s1` is defined on the first line and it is known to the inner queries. The inner queries will not be executed before hand. However, for each line in the outer most query (s1) the inner block will be executed.